# How do i stop what i think is a devcode window from appearing

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm not a programmer or web expert - just a stupid internet user. Firstly i hope i'm in the correct place to ask my question  (If not, please advise where i should go to ask the following question.)

To my annoyance, a window appears (which i think is a devcode window) on the right hand side of my screen without my wanting it.  Obviously i've activated it somehow inadvertently. 
I can close it by clicking the close button at top right of the window but it soon reappears and i have to close it repeatedly.

I think there must be a simple way of keeping the window closed.

Can anyone please advise me how to do that.

(I would like to attach a screenshot of my screen, but i can't see a button for appending it to my question.)

Thank you for any help you can give me.  Apologies, if i'm in the incorrect forum or have breached any rules or conventions you have you have.

Comment: Without a screenshot it's absolutely impossible to help. You can at least add a link to it in the question. However indeed, this question is off-topic here. Please post on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

DevTools will open on the following keyboard shortcuts: Shift-Ctrl-I or F12. The context and side menus also have items that will open DevTools.

To close DevTools, use the ESC key or F12.

Without knowing exactly what you were doing, it's impossible to tell why DevTools opened. The DevTools window should not open 'automatically.'

Comment: There is a strong probability that I'm accidentally hitting F12.